# В CSS коде 11 ошибок

Tags: css

```html
{ background: url(Мил.png)  no-repeat;
    '<style>'
        a img {
        border: 3px solid #c79316;
                '}'
       
        a:visited img {
        border: 3px solid #c716bd; 
                    }
    '</style>'

    'background-size: 100%;'
    'background-color: yellow(74,155,204);'
    'background-attachment:bisque;}'
    
    body { background:  no-repeat left top;
    background-size:50%px 80%px; 
    font-family: Times New Roman, cursive;
    }
    
    a {
        color 'rgb'(238,13,6,1);
    }
    
    #container {
                 margin: 30px auto;
                 
                 width: 800px;
                 height: 870px; }
                
     #header {
                background: #7CC8FF;
                width: 780px; 
                height: 160px;
                border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                border-top-left-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 7px 8px 153px 17px rgba(125,200,255,1);
                
                }
     #menu {
                background:#BEBEBE;
                width: 780px;
                height: 34px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
    #content {  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
                width: 760px;
                height: 637px;
                border-top-right-radius: 0px;
                border-top-left-radius: 0px;
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-right:10px;
    }
     #footer { 
                line-height:40px;
                background:rgba(124,192,238,0.5);
                width: 780px; 
                height: 39px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 70px 70px 153px 17px rgba(250,250,5,0.5);
                }
    
    p{text-align:justify;
    font-family:times new roman;
    font-size:14pt;}
    img {-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 13px 153px 17px rgba(176,176,157,0.2);}
    
    #menulast {
        background:#BEBEBE;
                width: 780px;
                height: 34px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 21px;
        
    }
    
    #ifram {
        margin-left:25px;
    }
    #headfoto 
    
    {
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
        
    }
    '</center>'
    '</center>'
```

Comment: Каких ошибок?) по вашему коду я вижу очень много ошибок... какие у вас?

Comment: Ну как минимум кавычки одинарные, зачем теги `style` обернуты в них (`center` тоже), зачем вот это `'}'`, 3 строки что ниже `'</style>'` тоже обернуты в кавычки; `color 'rgb'(238,13,6,1);`, где двоеточие после `color`, почему `rgb` в кавычках + там есть четвертый параметр, а `rgb` принимает 3. Ну а так в целом, то не понятно что здесь вообще происходит, часть стилей в тегах `style`, часть вне, два закрывающих `center`. Это вообще как `background-size:50%px 80%px;` проценты в пикселях?

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно ничего, но попробуйте изменить ваш код таким образом:

```
    <style>
        a img {
        border: 3px solid #c79316;
        }
       
        a:visited img {
        border: 3px solid #c716bd; 
        background-size: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(74,155,204);
        background-attachment:bisque;
    }
    
    body { 
        background:  no-repeat left top;
        background-size:50px 80px; 
        font-family: Times New Roman, cursive;
    }
    
    a {
        color: rgb(238,13,6,1);
    }
    
    #container {
                 margin: 30px auto;
                 
                 width: 800px;
                 height: 870px; 
     }
                
     #header {
                background: #7CC8FF;
                width: 780px; 
                height: 160px;
                border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                border-top-left-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 7px 8px 153px 17px rgba(125,200,255,1);
                
                }
     #menu {
                background:#BEBEBE;
                width: 780px;
                height: 34px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
    #content {  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
                width: 760px;
                height: 637px;
                border-top-right-radius: 0px;
                border-top-left-radius: 0px;
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-right:10px;
    }
     #footer { 
                line-height:40px;
                background:rgba(124,192,238,0.5);
                width: 780px; 
                height: 39px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 70px 70px 153px 17px rgba(250,250,5,0.5);
                }
    
    p{
            text-align:justify;
            font-family:times new roman;
            font-size:14pt;
    }

    img {
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 7px 13px 153px 17px rgba(176,176,157,0.2);
    }
    
    #menulast {
        background:#BEBEBE;
        width: 780px;
        height: 34px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 21px;
    }
    
    #ifram {
        margin-left:25px;
    }
    #headfoto 
    
    {
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
        
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Парочка ошибочек осталась: `background-color: yellow(74,155,204);`, `color rgb(238,13,6,1);`,

Comment: @Simon, спасибо, изменил, так же в коде присутствует сверху `background: url(Мил.png)  no-repeat;`, которые не понятно куда поставить, а автор вопроса, видимо в css не очень разбирается